# How to execute multiple mysql queries together in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to a select query and an insert query that I want to do them together using function(mysql_query),but it's not working.
I'm tying to do somthing like this:

```
$sql="select * from texts; insert into date ('time') values ('2012');";
mysql_query($sql);
```

is there any way to do it?

Comment: I dont think there are such type of query... but if there is let me know :)

Comment: @caesar  What do you expect as output?.   The  tuples of 'texts'  or  the  status of that insert?.  !!!

Comment: `mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple queries execution.

Comment: you can try use INSERT ... SELECT feature of mysql. full documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: You can execute 2 queries, since they don't seem related... you can also create a PROCEDURE that executes that insert and also that select.

Answer (score 5):

`mysql_query()` sends a unique query **(multiple queries are not supported)** .
That's the default behaviour.However there is a bypass for this.

However the result code of the first query alone will be given as output of `mysql_query()` if you do this.

You just have to pass flag 65536 as mysql_connect's 5th parameter . the flag is defined in [MySQL Client flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags).

```
#define CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS 65536 /* Enable/disable multi-stmt support */
#define CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS 131072 /* Enable/disable multi-results */
```

So edit your `mysql_connect()` code to match this:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, false, 65536);
```

**Warning:**

1. You will get  the  result of `mysql_query($query)` for the first query **only** in the  given `$query` .  You can try  concatenating  `131072` with `65536` for getting multiple results.
2. This will not work on PHP  < 4.3.0
3. This will not work if `sql.safe_mode` is set as 1 in *php.ini*

---

Another alternative will be to use `mysqli`  instead of `mysql` library. It supports  `$mysqli->multi_query()`  and  gives  output within an array for each query.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL don't allow passing more than one select query in single statement.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` doesn't support multiple queries execution in normal way.
use something like below.

```
<?php
$str="query1;query2;"; // say $str="select * from texts; insert into date ('time') values ('2012');";

$query = explode(';',$str);

// Run the queries
foreach($query as $index => $sql)
{
   $result = mysql_query($sql);    
   // Perform an additional operations here
}
?>
```

Comment: oh its you.. :) ha ha, yeah that's a new info to me(65536)

Answer (score 0):

None of the mysql api can deal with several queries simultaneously, even mysql consol utility parses your input and executes one query after another and php's mysql_query doesn't. You just can write your own function doing it or just put all queries in an array and execute mysql_query for each element in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_multi_query function but with PHP mysqli extension. (I recommend you to use mysqli instead of mysql extension of PHP because it includes much more features & facilities)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` sends a unique query

see [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

for multiple query you can see **[mysqli](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**